# Android/Gradle: specify a dependency for a subset of build types

Tags: java, android, groovy, gradle, raygun

The android project I'm working on has 3 build types - `debug`, `qa` and `release`:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        ...
    }
    qa {
        ...
    }
    debug {
        ...
    }
}
```

I would like to have a dependency (crash reporting library) only apply to `debug` and `qa` but not `release`.

I guess it could be done by duplicating build-type specific compile lines like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    debugCompile 'com.mindscapehq.android:raygun4android:1.3.0:sources'
    qaCompile    'com.mindscapehq.android:raygun4android:1.3.0:sources'
}
```

Is there a way to do this without duplication?

Comment: what's your concern about the duplication? is it that you when versions change you have to do it in multiple places? if so, just use a variable for the version and use that as the dependency. `ext { raygunVersion = 'com.mind....:1.3.0:sources' }` then `dependencies { debugCompile raygunVersion }`, is how we do it in builds.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over build types in dependencies

```
dependencies {
    ...
    android.buildTypes.each { type ->
        if(type.name.equals("debug") || type.name.equals("qa")) {
            compile('com.mindscapehq.android:raygun4android:1.3.0:sources')
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this didn't seem to compile the dependency into the project. There were compilation errors indicating source files from this library weren't found.

Comment: Try without sources compile('com.mindscapehq.android:raygun4android:1.3.0')

Comment: @user1405990 I tried on my project, everything is fine. post your whole gradle file, because this is correct answer

Comment: I tried it but in both cases, "release" and "build" Build Variant Android Studio tries to use the the libs selected for "build" only:
dependencies {
android.buildTypes.each { type ->
        if (type.name == "debug") {
            compile(name:'library-debug', ext:'aar')
        } else {
            compile(name:'library-release', ext:'aar')
        }
    }

Comment: Error is: "Multiple dex files define Lcom/my/package/Classname"